# Graphics Tablet not working only in 3D View

Tags: interface, 3d-view, texture-painting, sculpting, vertex-paint

I have a Huion Q11K graphics tablet. Only the stylus pressure doesn't seem to work. I can use the pen to click on menu buttons and manipulate the view just fine. In fact holding shift while sculpting works with the stylus for smoothing. Only pen pressure in the 3D View doesn't work.

Also with ScreenCast enabled the pen registers a left click but has no effect.

I've spent a few hours looking for solutions but it seems that no one else has ever had this problem... So I'm hoping it's something stupid that I'm missing.

Comment: In your brush settings you need to hit the  pressure icon on the right of the slider. The slider then defines the range that the pressure of your stylus is mapped to.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. And I was sure it was what I was missing but it still doesn't work.  The other thing to note is that it works, with pressure, if I hold CTRL, but 'Add'itive. Whereas I would expect it to be Subtractive. So... If I don't hold CTRL the mouse left click is additive and the pen does nothing; If I hold CTRL Left Mouse is subtractive and the pen is additive.

Comment: very strange, my Huion tablet worked right out of the box so I'm not sure how to help

Comment: Okay, got it fixed. Not 100% sure, but I believe the problem was caused by Windows Ink being disabled. I had disabled Ink in my quest to get my old monoprice tablet fixed. I tried re-enabling it but I couldn't get it to show up in the tray. Due to an unrelated issue, I had to re-install Windows which fixed everything. So, it was either Ink was missing or something was not right in Windows. Note, prior to re-installing Windows I had uninstalled and re-installed both Blender and Huion drivers to no avail.