# Huion Q11k Click not rigistred in 3d view

Tags: 3d-view, sculpting

I just got a Huion Q11K. It works perfectly except inside the blender 3d view ( The main reason I got it).

When I try to sculpt the clicks sometimes register and sometimes don't.

If I move around and sculpt it works then it stops. When I press `ctrl` it doesn't substract unless I pan around and click again.

I think it might be related to this thread [Graphics Tablet not working only in 3D View](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/97068/graphics-tablet-not-working-only-in-3d-view) which is closed.

Comment: Question is hardware related, perhaps also related to configuration on yout local machine. there are other support channels for these kind of questions. Not sure why this question needs to be reopened. Also not clear if the action that is posted in the closed question did work or not (disable Ink).

Comment: The tablet works fine with every other software. The problem only effects blender 3d View. Even blender menus work fine. Maybe there is an option in blender that might fix that. This is my question.

Comment: I doubt there is anything to do on the blender side. It is likely an issue with the configuration on the operating system and/or drivers for the device. Check whatever control panel you might have for it and make sure that it is mapping the correct left, and right clicks. For wacom tablets there is an option to customize the tablet/pen for different applications, maybe it is possible on your device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't a problem with blender as everyone said. But Blender was the only program that got affected with this.

When setting the pencil buttons in Huion, I changed the switch brush to middle click so I can move around. It turns out it didn't change it but added it so the button does both. I removed switch brush and it works as a charm.

I hope someone finds this useful. And close this thread :-)